# Getting value in between keys using XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I Need to get the value in the XML file in between each key. For example, I have a list of keys to be used, and each key there's a corresponding output element. The keys can be placed anywhere, there is no proper order in where the key is needed to place. I need to do this in XSLT 2.0, and I don't have any idea on how will I do this.

**Keys:**       ***Element:***

**/OPDH/** - ***ROOT/ELEMENT1/ABCD***

**/EKPH/** - ***ROOT/ELEMENT2/POIU***

**/SGDE/** - ***ROOT/ELEMENT3/WXYZ***

...some other keys...

NOTE: Keys: is in BOLD, and Element is in ITALIC BOLD.

If I have a sample input like this:

1.)

```
<DATA>/OPDH/FLOWING SOLUTION/SGDE/Number0983713/EKPH/Sample test/some other keys/</DATA>
```

OR it can be:

2.)

```
<DATA>/some other keys/afdsf/SGDE/Number0983713/some other keys/PIHSAGA/OPDH/FLOWING SOLUTION/some other keys/No exception/EKPH/Sample test/some other keys/</DATA>
```

The expected output should look like this:

1.

```
<ROOT>
   <ELEMENT1>
      <ABCD>FLOWING SOLUTION</ABCD>
   </ELEMENT1>
   <ELEMENT2>
      <POIU>Sample test</POIU>
   </ELEMENT2>
   <ELEMENT3>
      <SGDE>Number0983713</SGDE>
   </ELEMENT3>
   ...some other keys...
</ROOT>
```

2.

```
<ROOT>
  ...some other keys...
   <ELEMENT3>
      <SGDE>Number0983713</SGDE>
   </ELEMENT3>
  ...some other keys...
   <ELEMENT1>
      <ABCD>FLOWING SOLUTION</ABCD>
   </ELEMENT1>
  ...some other keys...
   <ELEMENT2>
      <POIU>Sample test</POIU>
   </ELEMENT2>
  ...some other keys...
</ROOT>
```

Thank you.

Comment: This is very confusing: where is this "list of keys", and in what format is it? Can it be hard-coded into the stylesheet?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a partial suggestion that uses `analyze-string`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs mf" version="2.0">

    <xsl:param name="keys">
        <element key="/OPDH/">ROOT/ELEMENT1/ABCD</element>
        <element key="/EKPH/">ROOT/ELEMENT2/POIU</element>
        <element key="/SGDE/">ROOT/ELEMENT3/WXYZ</element>
        <element key="/some other keys/">ROOT/FOO/BAR</element>
    </xsl:param>

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:variable name="pattern" as="xs:string"
        select="concat('(', string-join($keys/element/@key, '|'), ')', '(.*?)', '(', string-join($keys/element/@key, '|'), ')')"/>

    <xsl:key name="ref" match="element" use="@key"/>

    <xsl:function name="mf:extract" as="element()*">
        <xsl:param name="input" as="xs:string"/>
        <xsl:analyze-string select="$input" regex="{$pattern}">
            <xsl:matching-substring>
                <xsl:if test="position() eq 1">
                    <element path="{key('ref', regex-group(1), $keys)}">
                        <xsl:value-of select="regex-group(2)"/>
                    </element>
                    <xsl:sequence
                        select="mf:extract(substring($input, string-length(concat(regex-group(1), regex-group(2))) + 1))"
                    />
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:matching-substring>
        </xsl:analyze-string>
    </xsl:function>

    <xsl:template match="DATA">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:sequence select="mf:extract(.)"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This transforms the input

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
    <DATA>/OPDH/FLOWING SOLUTION/SGDE/Number0983713/EKPH/Sample test/some other keys/</DATA>
    <DATA>/some other keys/afdsf/SGDE/Number0983713/some other keys/PIHSAGA/OPDH/FLOWING SOLUTION/some other keys/No exception/EKPH/Sample test/some other keys/</DATA>
</Root>
```

into list of elements with the extracted data and the path to build:

```
    <DATA>
   <element path="ROOT/ELEMENT1/ABCD">FLOWING SOLUTION</element>
   <element path="ROOT/ELEMENT3/WXYZ">Number0983713</element>
   <element path="ROOT/ELEMENT2/POIU">Sample test</element>
</DATA>
    <DATA>
   <element path="ROOT/FOO/BAR">afdsf</element>
   <element path="ROOT/ELEMENT3/WXYZ">Number0983713</element>
   <element path="ROOT/FOO/BAR">PIHSAGA</element>
   <element path="ROOT/ELEMENT1/ABCD">FLOWING SOLUTION</element>
   <element path="ROOT/FOO/BAR">No exception</element>
   <element path="ROOT/ELEMENT2/POIU">Sample test</element>
</DATA>
```

I am not quite sure whether that is doing the right job as I am not sure what determines the order and contents of the two samples you have provided and what e.g. `/some other keys/` is meant to express. Tell us whether the result has the data you want or clarify your question and the samples you have shown. It should be easy to generate the XML from the above intermediary results once we have established that the right data is extracted.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote very little about keys, so I assume that:

1. Your input file contains **both**:

   - key list (in `KEYS` tag),
   - actual source (in `DATA` tag).
2. Both these tags are children of the source `ROOT` tag.
3. `KEYS` tag contains in each row a pair of key value and output path, where
   respective content for this key shoud be placed.

Assume that your **full** input is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ROOT>
  <KEYS>
    /OPDH/ - ROOT/ELEMENT1/ABCD
    /EKPH/ - ROOT/ELEMENT2/POIU
    /SGDE/ - ROOT/ELEMENT3/SGDE
  </KEYS>
  <DATA>/OPDH/FLOWING SOLUTION/SGDE/Number0983713/EKPH/Sample test/</DATA>
</ROOT>
```

Then you can write the XSLT as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="ROOT">
    <xsl:copy>
      <!-- Divide KEYS into rows -->
      <xsl:variable name="keys_1" select="tokenize(KEYS, '&#xA;')"/>
      <!-- # of rows -->
      <xsl:variable name="nn" select="count($keys_1)"/>
      <!-- Drop 1st and last (empty) row -->
      <xsl:variable name="keys" select="subsequence($keys_1, 2, $nn - 2)"/> 
      <!-- Divide DATA into tokens -->
      <xsl:variable name="data_1" select="tokenize(DATA, '/')"/>
      <!-- # of tokens -->
      <xsl:variable name="nn" select="count($data_1)"/>
      <!-- Drop 1st and last (empty) token -->
      <xsl:variable name="data" select="subsequence($data_1, 2, $nn - 2)"/> 
      <!-- Generate output data for each row from keys -->
      <xsl:for-each select="$keys">
        <!-- Divide the keys row into tokens -->
        <xsl:variable name="parts" select="tokenize(., '/')"/>
        <!-- # of tokens -->
        <xsl:variable name="nn" select="count($parts)"/>
        <!-- Source key - token No 2 (after the 1st '/') -->
        <xsl:variable name="srcKey" select="$parts[2]"/>
        <!-- path - tokens after 'ROOT' -->
        <xsl:variable name="path" select="subsequence($parts, 4)"/> 
        <!-- Open tags given in path -->
        <xsl:for-each select="$path">
          <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
          <!-- Spacing -->
          <xsl:variable name="nn" select="position()"/>
          <xsl:value-of select=
            "string-join((for $i in 1 to $nn return '  '), '')"/>
          <!-- Print opening tag -->
          <xsl:value-of select="concat('&lt;', ., '&gt;')"
            disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <!-- Find position of the source key in data -->
        <xsl:variable name="ind" select="index-of($data, $srcKey)[1]"/>
        <!-- Get data from the next token -->
        <xsl:value-of select="$data[$ind + 1]"/>
        <!-- Close tags given in path -->
        <xsl:for-each select="reverse($path)">
          <xsl:variable name="nn" select="position()"/>
          <!-- Spacing and NewLine - but not for the most inner tag -->
          <xsl:if test="$nn &gt; 1">
            <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select=
              "string-join((for $i in 1 to last() - $nn + 1 return '  '), '')"/>
          </xsl:if>
          <!-- Print closing tag -->
          <xsl:value-of select="concat('&lt;/', ., '&gt;')"
            disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:for-each>
      <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```